# MongoDB database creation issue

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using MongoDB. All I want to do is add a collection to a database I have created. I verified before I even started that the database existed by running the command "show dbs". However, when I try to add the collection to that database, it says that this database is undefined. Any thoughts or suggestions? Here were the commands I typed in terminal

1. use myDB
2. myDB.myCol.insert({"id":"1"})
     the response I got from this command is "myDB is not defined" even 
     though I verified that it exists with the command "show dbs".

Comment: show us the steps that you are doing

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you're attempting to add a collection (and how you're specifying the database). Did you switch to that database? (`use <dbname>`)? Are you implicitly creating the collection via a save to it?

Comment: Sorry. I just added the steps so you can see them now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `db` instead of the name of the database in your insert command:

```
db.myCol.insert({"id":"1"})
```

`use MyDB` sets which database `db` refers to.